# Keeping a view always in memory in Flex Mobile?

Tags: flex-mobile

Is there a way to achieve this? At first I thought that `desctructionPolicy = 'never'` would allow me to do this, but after spending a lot of time struggling with it, it seems I was wrong and the feature doesn't work as I thought.

I could keep all the relevant data I need of that view and restore all components to the expected state, but I find that to be a bit cumbersome, and I'm a bit surprised there is no way to do this. When I navigate through several views, and then go back up to the view I'd like to persist, it is there with its last state.

Can't I restore the view in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible. At the end I had to store and restore the whole view.

It would be nice if Adobe would allow for this, luckily this may be one of those things where Flex being donated to the Apache foundation would come handy.